# Update field in array of objects in json postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have postgres database with next json in my table

```
{"jobTitle":"Technical Writer","distance":60,"skills":[{"name":"Bootstrap (Front-End Framework)","isPrimary":true,"type":""}, {"name":"Javascript","isPrimary":false,"type":""}]}
```

I need to update field "skills" depends on "isPrimary" value in each item there. If "isPrimary" false, update to 1, otherwise to 5.

I have next query

```
UPDATE t
SET body = jsonb_set(body::jsonb, '{skills}', s.skills_updated::jsonb)
FROM (
  SELECT
  jsonb_agg(
     jsonb_set(skills::jsonb, '{isPrimary}', 
        CASE
            WHEN skills ->> 'isPrimary' = 'true' THEN '5'::jsonb
            ELSE '1'::jsonb
        END
    )
  ) as skills_updated
  FROM t,
    json_array_elements(body -> 'skills') as skills
) s;
```

This query working incorrectly - it's accumulating all skills across all records in table and then setting this whole array in each record. this is my fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/m28W7tPy

For instance, if I have next three records:

```
{"jobTitle":"Writer","distance":60, "skills": [{ "isPrimary": "true", "name": "Node.js" },{ "isPrimary": "false", "name": "Python" },{ "isPrimary": "false", "name": "Javascript" }]}

{"jobTitle":"Writer","distance":60, "skills": [{ "isPrimary": "true", "name": "Mysql" },{ "isPrimary": "false", "name": "Nest.js" }]}

{"jobTitle":"Writer","distance":60, "skills": [{ "isPrimary": "true", "name": "Postgres" },{ "isPrimary": "false", "name": "Typescript" }]}
```

I want to update just "isPrimary" for all above records and get in result next

```
{"jobTitle":"Writer","distance":60, "skills": [{ "isPrimary": 5, "name": "Node.js" },{ "isPrimary": 1, "name": "Python" },{ "isPrimary": 1, "name": "Javascript" }]}

{"jobTitle":"Writer","distance":60, "skills": [{ "isPrimary": 5, "name": "Mysql" },{ "isPrimary": 1, "name": "Nest.js" }]}

{"jobTitle":"Writer","distance":60, "skills": [{ "isPrimary": 5, "name": "Postgres" },{ "isPrimary": 1, "name": "Typescript" }]}
```

when I'm getting after running my query

```
{"jobTitle":"Writer","distance":60, "skills": [{ "isPrimary": 5, "name": "Node.js" },{ "isPrimary": 1, "name": "Python" },{ "isPrimary": 1, "name": "Javascript" }, { "isPrimary": 5, "name": "Mysql" },{ "isPrimary": 1, "name": "Nest.js" }, { "isPrimary": 5, "name": "Postgres" },{ "isPrimary": 1, "name": "Typescript" }]}

{"jobTitle":"Writer","distance":60, "skills": [{ "isPrimary": 5, "name": "Node.js" },{ "isPrimary": 1, "name": "Python" },{ "isPrimary": 1, "name": "Javascript" }, { "isPrimary": 5, "name": "Mysql" },{ "isPrimary": 1, "name": "Nest.js" }, { "isPrimary": 5, "name": "Postgres" },{ "isPrimary": 1, "name": "Typescript" }]}

{"jobTitle":"Writer","distance":60, "skills": [{ "isPrimary": 5, "name": "Node.js" },{ "isPrimary": 1, "name": "Python" },{ "isPrimary": 1, "name": "Javascript" }, { "isPrimary": 5, "name": "Mysql" },{ "isPrimary": 1, "name": "Nest.js" }, { "isPrimary": 5, "name": "Postgres" },{ "isPrimary": 1, "name": "Typescript" }]}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you share the expected output?

Comment: updated post with expected result

Comment: Use a proper, normalized data model, and the problem will go away automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your query is that you're not keeping trace of each "*id*" value, nor you're matching it inside the update statement. Adding the "*id*" selection inside the subquery, and the final `WHERE` condition to the `UPDATE` statement, can solve your problem.

```
UPDATE t
SET body = jsonb_set(body::jsonb, '{skills}', s.skills_updated::jsonb)
FROM (
  SELECT id,
  jsonb_agg(
     jsonb_set(skills::jsonb, '{isPrimary}', 
        CASE
            WHEN skills ->> 'isPrimary' = 'true' THEN '5'::jsonb
            ELSE '1'::jsonb
        END
    )
  ) as skills_updated
  FROM t,
    json_array_elements(body -> 'skills') as skills
  GROUP BY id
) s
WHERE t.id = s.id ;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2RScmjnNh4ym3vNdUfw88z/0).